# changing lock screen effect

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, lock-screens

I upgraded my samsung phone galaxy note 4 to Android 6.0.1. There is now an animation for the lock screen that I don't find convenient. It looks like a a black curtain is closing. How can I change that ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would go to <kbd>settings</kbd> > <kbd>lock screen</kbd> but it could also be in <kbd>settings</kbd> > <kbd>security</kbd>.